Place the placeholder at the nearest border between two item
I have a mat table that displays nested items like a tree list. I want to add drag and drop to move items in and out of nodes/items.
To do so I check if I hover the inner center 75% of a row. If so then the dragged item will be nested under the hovered item and the move indicator should be hidden (does not work at the moment; [hidden]="true" on the placeholder breaks the UI). If not, so I'm hovering nearly between two rows, the indicator should show where the item would be moved to.
I use the drag placeholder to create the indicator. The problem is that the placeholder is shown at the top of the hovered items although I hover the bottom edge. In this case the indicator/placeholder should be at the bottom.
Here is a reproducible example of what I mean: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vs1krp
How can I configure or change the behavior to only move the placeholder and move-index if I'm near the corresponding border?

To fix the drag and drop in your component, we need to ensure that the Angular CDK Drag and Drop functionality integrates smoothly with the Angular Material table.
You need to ensure that cdkDrag and cdkDropList directives are correctly applied to the table rows, and that the event listeners for drag and drop are properly handled.
Your hovering logic also seems a bit complicated, which might not be necessary. Instead, we can rely on simpler CSS-based solutions for indicating hover states.
I did some changes and refactors on your Stackblitz example, I am not sure if this is the outcome you wanted but I hope so it helps.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-am4qk5?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-drag-drop.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-drag-drop.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-drag-drop.component.scss

I don't know if you posted the wrong link to the wrong project, but this does not solve any of my problems. The placeholder is no 2px indicator but a full row that swap places with another row immediately after hovering which makes dragging rows on top of each other impossible. Also I can't find any of your CSS-based solutions for indicating hover states. Also I use js and not css for hovering logic because based on the position of the mouse above a row different actions should be invoked
